# CRS - Dynamically change a report locale

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-server

I am using CRS (Crystal Reports Server) 2008 v1 and we are viewing reports through a JSP application deployed on the built-in Tomcat server that comes with CRS. I would like to know how to dynamically change the locale of reports through this application (i.e. through Java). The below code seems to work fine for CRS XI but it is not working in CRS 2008 v1. The locale seems to get stuck to Swedish regional settings in my case!

```
IInfoObject infoObject = (IInfoObject)infoObjects.get(0);     

IReportAppFactory reportAppFactory = (IReportAppFactory) enterpriseSession.getService("RASReportFactory");

ReportClientDocument clientDoc = reportAppFactory.openDocument(infoObject, 0, **java.util.Locale.US**);
```

How can we modify this locale setting to work with CRS 2008. It seems that openDocument with the java.util.Locale.US has no effect on the result we get. It is not changing anything!

We changed the regional settings of the machine where the server is installed and we also changed the settings from the CMC and we also reinstalled the CRS using English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since time was pressing hard and the documentation did not shed any light on this topic, I had to find a workaround to this.

Well, it was all related to the NLS_LANG registry setting. This was having a priority over any other settings I put in the application. Again, this was not an issue with CRS XI but it is a damn issue with CRS 2008.